# WEB2PY DAL how to create a query that matches a list of field values

Tags: web2py

Creating a grid with a query matching a single value is OK with the following code (query variable  is then passed to SQLFORM.grid constructor)

```
query = (db.QUALORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER == '482990B')
```

How to match several values ? the followin code

```
query = (db.QUALORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER in ['482990B'])
```

raises error :

```
  File "C:\web2py_src\web2py\gluon\sqlhtml.py", line 2316, in grid
db = query._db
```

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '_db'

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.belongs()` method](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#belongs):

```
db.QUALORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER.belongs(['482990B'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony